# Recurring Tasks in Delajed Jobs without firing up Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

If I need to create recurring tasks in delayed jobs, what is a clean solution? I have an import task that I want to run every 5 minutes, but I don't want to fire up rails/rake in order to tell it to create a Delayed job that can be picked up. If Rails is already running on a system, perhaps I can just create an HTTP request that will make the rails app fire off a DJ? I could put that cron task in a ruby script which  runs every 5 minutes, making requests to a server, but without firing up rails. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fork of delayed_job has recurrence built right in (and there may be other forks that do the same):

http://github.com/andrewroth/delayed_job

Comment: This actually is exactly what I need. I can use Whenever to load the DJs at boot time and then they will run when I need them.

Answer (score 0):

The `cron` approach still seems to be quite clean. It need only involve running a `rake` invocation, not a full Rails server. Rake doesn't need Rails to be running to work.

However if you really don't like that approach then you could arrange for the *recurring jobs* to be re-queue themselves when they are being processed setting a `run_at` time to 5 minutes (or whatever) in the future. Obviously you'd need to prime the queue the first time and make sure the `delayed_job` server stays running

Answer (score 0):

About that... I have the same desire,
I'm planning to have a *cron* to fire up a *curl* request at a specific route at my site every 5 minutes, so it runs a action with the result, and I'm gonna be pretty sure it only ran once.

My purposes includes: Awarding Badges and compiling  some Averages